# How to find the mirror of an identity matrix without using numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, logic

Here I have an identity matrix that goes from top left to bottom right. I'm trying to flip it so I can get a row of 1's going from top right to bottom left but I don't want to use numpy. But I just cant work out how to do it...

```
num = int(input("enter your number"))
for i in range(0, num):
    for j in range(0, num):
        if (i == j):
            print(1, sep=" ", end=" ")
        else:
            print(0, sep=" ", end=" ")
    print()
```

Example:
Input:  4
Output:

> 1 0 0 0
> 0 1 0 0
> 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 0 1

Comment: You "flip"/mirror an identity matrix just like any other - I think you want to *create* it anew (saner&simpler). What have you tried? What column does the 1 in row 0 need to go to? Row 1?

Comment: yes I suppose I do mean a new matrix but redrawn. I want the 1 starting in the top right of whatever size input the user enters if for example it was 4 and was overlaid onto the old one it would make an X shape. So I have been fiddling with the ```num``` input for range to see if it draws the matrix from the opposite direction but it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: use `if i + j + 1 == num:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simple relation between `column`, `row` and `num`

```
if i + j + 1 == num:
```

---

Full code:

```
num = int(input("enter your number"))
for i in range(0, num):
    for j in range(0, num):
        if i + j + 1 == num:
            print(1, sep=" ", end=" ")
        else:
            print(0, sep=" ", end=" ")
    print()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other idea is to revers one range

```
for j in range(num-1, -1, -1):
```

---

Full code:

```
num = int(input("enter your number"))
for i in range(0, num):
    for j in range(num-1, -1, -1):
        if i == j:
            print(1, sep=" ", end=" ")
        else:
            print(0, sep=" ", end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant! It looks so obvious now! I cant believe I couldn't get to it! damn! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

To create an anti-diagonal matrix, put a 1 in every (row, column) where column = n-1 - row:

```
def anti_diagonal(n):
    """Return the n x n antidiagonal matrix as a list of lists. """
    return [ [ 0 if column != n-1 - row else 1 for column in range(n) 
             ] for row in range(n) ]
```